# What is the alternative for android:entries in code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

How to I send an String array to a listView from the code and have the emulator display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very general question... but the basic idea would be to create one of the usual Adapters, ArrayAdapter possibly in this case, initialize it with the String array and then call the ListView's setAdapter() method with that ArrayAdapter.